# Why does the poster attribute of the video element cause my video to offset?

Tags: css, html

I have a div containing HTML5 video as the background. I displaced it using a -Z-index to overlay a logo on top. I cannot figure out why the div containing the video is placing a margin between the menu bar and itself when I include the poster attribute in the video element.

Note: This works as desired when I remove the video element.

The attached screen shot has different colors for body and background of the menu bar for demo purposes, but here is a link to my site: 
http://eldonutshoppe.com/index2.html

Here is my code in question:

HTML:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed hidden" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/donutshoppe/"><img class="socialmedia" src="img/dsfb.svg"></a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://instagram.com/donutshoppe/"><img class="socialmedia" src="img/dsinstagram.svg"></a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7OPBnAhkrik-ZY1M2kk9Xw"><img class="socialmedia" src="img/dsyoutube.svg"></a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Subscribe to our Newsletter</a></li>
      </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="bg-video col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">

      <video preload="auto"  poster="/img/eldonutshoppe.svg" autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="video/uncletonyloop.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          <source src="video/uncletonyloop.webm" type="video/webm"/>
      </video>

      <div class="sslogo-video">
        <img class="sslogo-big" src="img/eldonutshoppe.svg">
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.eldonutshoppe.com/store/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg cta" role="button">Browse our Record Collection</a>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-video{
    height:100vh;
    padding: 0;
}

video{
    width:100%;
    opacity:.3;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Referring to the image, I cannot figure out what is causing the "white space" between the menu bar and the video. (On the site itself, the "white space" is black.
[image]

Comment: Did you inspect the element with your browser? Did you check `padding`? `margin`? `border`?

Comment: yes, i cannot see what's causing the offset

Comment: What are the values of those CSS parameters? Show the information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `poster` attribute in the `video` element, it is somehow altering the dimensions before the video starts loading and it becomes available. Since you already have the same image in another div you could try just removing the poster attribute.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: that fixed it! thanks. Any idea why poster is offsetting the video element? I was hoping to leave something in place of the video while it loaded..

Comment: TBH I have no idea, I've had similar issues in the past but couldn't find the reason anywhere.

Comment: CSS is not really my thing :P. Sorry I cannot give a reason of why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look at your site, in your app.css on line 96
change the following:

```
.video {
    position: absolute; <-- its currently set to fixed
}
```

Should do the trick :)

Comment: It doesn't help. If I open the inspector though and uncheck then check position, it works as desired. It works fine either way in Firefox but I'm having the offset issue with Chrome/Safari. I think this may be an issue when the DOM is being built? I was thinking to reset the property after page load using javascript, but there has to be a better way!

Comment: I tested in chrome and it worked when it was set to absolute, will double check

Comment: That's what I had originally but if it loads with position:absolute, it still needs to be reset. I'll change it now on my server back to absolute.